# Find certain line in file and extract part of it

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am trying to make a Bash script that will look in a file for a certain line (`IR Freq. = 23.23`) and copy the `23.23` from it and send it through serial interface (ttyS0).

The line will move around the file and the number will change a lot!

Comment: Please show us what you have so far. Also check out [ask]. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below script

grep -r "IR Freq." filename | cut -d '=' -f 2 | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'